# How to handle "Nullable value type may be null" (for TimeSpan) inside the sum() methode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, nullable, timespan, nullable-reference-types

In my Asp.net core project, I need to check for null `TimeSpan` properties.
This is my method:

```
 return result.Include(e => e.Episodes).AsEnumerable().Select(c => new ShowListCoursesViewModel()
            {
                CourseId = c.CourseId,
                CourseImageName = c.CourseImageName,
                CoursePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(c.CoursePrice),
                CourseTitle = c.CopurseTitle,
                CourseTotalTime = new TimeSpan(c.Episodes.Sum(t => t.EpisodeTimeLength.Value.Ticks) )
            }).Skip(skip).Take(take).OrderByDescending(d => d.CoursePrice).ToList();
```

It's showing a green squiggle under the `t.EpisodeTimeLength` and saying:

> Nullable value type may be null.

My `CourseTotalTime` property is nullable and also the EpisodeTimeLength is nullable too.

How can I interpret `null` values of `EpisodeTimeLength` as `00:00:00` in the `Sum`? Example: `[null, 01:00:00, 01:00:00]` should yield `02:00:00` in `CourseTotaltime`.

Comment: So you want to assign `null` to `CourseTotalTime` if _any_ `EpisodeTimeLength` is `null`, even if other values of `EpisodeTimeLength` belonging to the same course have non-null values? Is that correct?

Comment: No, I just want to have sum of my `EpisodeTimeLength` then if one of my `EpisodeTimeLength`s was null, considered it as "00:00:00".

Comment: So you want `CourseTotalTime` to be 00:00:00 if any `EpisodeTimeLength` is `null`?

Comment: Then you don't want to assign 00:00:00 to `CourseTotalTime` as you stated in your question. I suggest you edit your question to fix this.

Comment: I want the `Sum()` to consider the null as `00:00:00`. that's it

Comment: I don't think so. as i said in my question, I want to get rid of the green squiggle. So Idecided to replace the null values with `00:00:00` to be able to get rid of green squiggle!

Comment: @Llama would you take a look at this one please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69749529/how-to-order-the-entities-by-their-timespan-properties/69749661?noredirect=1#comment123297117_69749661

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude `null` values with `Where` before the `Sum`:

```
CourseTotalTime = new TimeSpan(
    c.Episodes
        .Where(t => t.EpisodeTimeLength.HasValue)
        .Sum(t => t.EpisodeTimeLength.Value.Ticks))
```

Alternatively, you can specify a default value to use when `t.EpisodeTimeLength` is `null`:

```
CourseTotalTime = new TimeSpan(
    c.Episodes
        .Sum(t => (t.EpisodeTimeLength ?? TimeSpan.Zero).Ticks))
```

This makes use of the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

[Demonstration of both approaches](https://rextester.com/BZZIA20922)

Comment: Yes. that's the thing that I was looking for. But in this case, the ';' symboles at the end of the sntences should be omitted :). Thank You very much.

Comment: Sorry that was a carry-over from my own testing :) I've removed the semicolons now.