# How to order the entities by their TimeSpan properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, sql-order-by, timespan

I'm working on an Asp.Net Core project and I need to sort my classes `Course.cs` by their total time.
I have an entity named "Course.cs" which has one-to-many relation with the entity `Episode.cs` so that each `Course.cs` has many `Episode.cs` inside itself.

My `Episode.cs` is:

```
public  class Episode
{
    [Key]
    public int EpisodeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "عنوان اپیزود")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="لطفا {0} را وارد کنید")]
    [MaxLength(ErrorMessage ="{0} نمیتواند بیش تر از {1}کاراکتر باشد")]
    public string EpisodeTitle { get; set; }
   
    public string EpisodeFileName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "مدت زمان اپیزود")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید")]
    
    public TimeSpan? EpisodeTimeLength { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "رایگان")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید")]
    public bool IsFree { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } 

    #region Navigation Properties

    [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
    public Course.Courses.Course Course { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

As you can see above, I have a property named `public TimeSpan? EpisodeTimeLength { get; set; }` and want to sort my `Course.cs`s depending on this property.

I tried this way:

```
_dbContext.Courses.Include(c => c.Episodes).AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(c => c.Episodes.Select(t => t.EpisodeTimeLength));
```

and then tried this way:

```
_dbContext.Courses.OrderByDescending(t => t.Episodes.Sum(s => s.EpisodeTimeLength ?? TimeSpan.Zero).Ticks));
```

but they are not compiled!

Would anybody help?

Comment: take a look to :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129795/storing-timespan-with-entity-framework-codefirst-sqldbtype-time-overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by summing timespans' total milliseconds:

```
var ordered = courses
    .Include(x => x.Episodes)
    .ToList()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Episodes.Sum(e => e.Length?.TotalMilliseconds ?? 0));
```

Full sample code below:

```
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var courses = new Course[]
            {
                new Course()
                {
                    Name = "Course 1",
                    Episodes = new List<Episode>()
                    {
                        new Episode(){ Length = null },
                        new Episode(){ Length = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) },
                    }
                },
                new Course()
                {
                    Name = "Course 2",
                    Episodes = new List<Episode>()
                    {
                        new Episode(){ Length = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) },
                        new Episode(){ Length = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6) },
                        new Episode(){ Length = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6) },
                    }
                },
                new Course()
                {
                    Name = "Course 3",
                    Episodes = new List<Episode>()
                    {
                        new Episode(){ Length = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) },
                        new Episode(){ Length = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6) },
                        new Episode(){ Length = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) },
                        new Episode(){ Length = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7) },
                    }
                },
            };
            var ordered = courses
                .Include(x => x.Episodes)
                .ToList()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Episodes.Sum(e => e.Length?.TotalMilliseconds ?? 0));

            foreach (var course in ordered) Console.WriteLine(course.Name);
        }
    }

    public class Course
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Episode
    {
        public TimeSpan? Length { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your  way as `result.Include(c => c.Episodes).OrderByDescending(c => c.Episodes.Sum(t => t.EpisodeTimeLength?.TotalMilliseconds ?? 0));` but showing red squiggle under `t.EpisodeTimeLength?.TotalMilliseconds ?? 0` and it says: **An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator**.

Comment: You shoud know that the `result` came from this setence: `IQueryable<Course> result = _context.Course;` and i'm using EF core!

Comment: @Hossein please see upate.

Comment: Showiing this error: **InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[Toplearn.DataLayer.Entities.Course.Courses.Course,System.Double]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Toplearn.DataLayer.Entities.Course.Courses.Course]'.**